# Sort the records based on time Gantt Chart

Tags: google-visualization

Do we have option to sort the records based on time in Gantt Chart using google charts api. my data are sorted internally based on some criteria. i searched in google site i didn't get any luck. please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data can be sorted before drawing the chart

```
// sort by start and end dates
data.sort([{column: 2}, {column: 3}]);
```

this will affect the order in the which the rows appear on the chart (y-axis)

the chart automatically sorts by date/time on the x-axis

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
    data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');
    data.addRows([
      ['Research', 'Find sources',
       new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
      ['Write', 'Write paper',
       null, new Date(2015, 0, 9), daysToMilliseconds(3), 25, 'Research,Outline'],
      ['Cite', 'Create bibliography',
       null, new Date(2015, 0, 7), daysToMilliseconds(1), 20, 'Research'],
      ['Complete', 'Hand in paper',
       null, new Date(2015, 0, 10), daysToMilliseconds(1), 0, 'Cite,Write'],
      ['Outline', 'Outline paper',
       null, new Date(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research']
    ]);

    // sort by start and end dates
    data.sort([{column: 2}, {column: 3}]);

    new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      data,
      {
        height: 275
      }
    );
  },
  packages:['gantt']
});

function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
  return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Actually I don't think the data can be sorted by the user.  The code above sorts by the default sort order, so doesn't it do nothing?  The original question seems odd because it's asking how to sort by the default (and only) sort order Google allows for Gantt charts.